# Verb for making enemy

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a single word verb for "making an enemy"? I know of 'alienate' which isn't close to what I want.

Comment: **Why** is alienate not close? How are you going to use your word? Please help the community; otherwise it's just a guessing game.

Comment: Because alienate does not mean "making someone an enemy"

Comment: Well, [one thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/alienate?&o=100074&s=t) says "cause unfriendliness/hostility" and suggests "set against", so it's a potential fit.

Comment: Right. I was going for the consensus: make (someone) feel isolated or estranged.
"an urban environment which would alienate its inhabitants"

Comment: I understand that this was a very 'simple question'. However, I don't agree with lack of research. I did spend time googling and searching on english SE.
Also, every usage of alienate I have seen has been in the sense of 'making alien = isolating, segregating...', and not making enemy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Antagonize](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/antagonize) comes to mind

> to make hostile or unfriendly; make an enemy or antagonist of:
>   His speech antagonized many voters.<sub>[dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/antagonize)</sub>

Comment: I invented the word "befoe" for this purpose, past tense "befoed."